# Real-time Synchronization

Tags: sql-server, replication, architecture

I have created an application in .Net with Microsoft SQL Server for desktop with a local database and an online application with an online database.

*Data entry will be done on both platforms in real-time.*

How can I synchronize the desktop database with the online database (as primary) in real-time without any data loss?